# How do I drift?

Tags: ps4, batman-arkham-knight

**How do I drift?** Does the game give any indication when I'm drifting? The controls say L+R2+Square, but that doesn't seem to work. The "Mental Blocked" Riddler challenge gives bonus time for drifting, but I don't see any indication that I've drifted or earned any bonus time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drifting is indeed performed the way you described, that is: by steering (<kbd>L</kbd>) while accelerating (<kbd>R2</kbd>) and using the hand brakes (<kbd>□</kbd>) all at the same time.

> The "Mental Blocked" Riddler challenge gives bonus time for drifting, but I don't see any indication that I've drifted or earned any bonus time.

That's because you don't explicitly *gain* time per se when drifting. Instead, the timer *slows down*.

If you pay attention to the timer, you'll notice it runs noticeably slower when drifting. I'm not sure by how much, but it takes several seconds in real time for the timer to go down by 1 second.